# Can i use my WatiN tests to stresstest?

Tags: testing, watin, mbunit, stress-testing

In my current project we are testing our ASP.NET GUI using [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) and [Mbunit](http://www.mbunit.com/).

When I was writing the tests I realized that it would be great if we also could use all of these for stresstesting. Currently we are using [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) to stresstest but then we have to script our cases all over again which for many reasons isent that good.

I have been trying to find a tool that can use my existing tests to create load on the site and record stats, but so far i have found noting. Is there such a tool or is there an easy way to create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have issues on our build server when running WatiN tests as it often throws timeouts trying to access the Internet Explorer COM component. It seems to hang randomly while waiting for the total page to load.

Given this, I would not recommend it for stress testing as the results will be inaccurate and the tests are likely to be slow.

I would recommend [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for making threaded calls to the HTTP requests that your GUI is making

Comment: +1 for an requests based solution. I agree with the solution, although not the cause. Those random "hangs" where probably the app hitting the timeouts i.e. not supporting the load.

Answer (score 2):

For load testing there is a tool which looks promising - LoadStorm. Free for 25 users. It has zero deployment needs as this is a cloud based service.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a load controller for your stress testing.  It could take your watin tests and run them in a multithreaded/multiprocessed way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using Selenium instead of WatiN, check out BrowserMob for [browser-based load testing](http://browsermob.com). I'm one of the Selenium RC authors and started BrowserMob to provide a new way to load test. By using real browsers, rather than simulated traffic, tests end up being much easier to script and maintain.